# How to get a single name for multiple name properties in DBPedia with SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, owl, dbpedia

I need to get persons' names from DBPedia, but the problem is that not every person  has the `dbpprop:fullname` property, sometimes it only has the `dbpprop:name` or the `rdfs:label` property.

To clarify: I want to query for the name with a preference for the first property, if that doesn't exist get the second property, and if that doesn't exist get the third property, etc.

So how could I get person's name from the

```
   dbpprop:name (person name = [dbpprop:name] if no [dbpprop:fullname])
```

and from

```
  rdfs:name (person name = [rdfs:name] if no both [dbpprop:fullname] and [dbpprop:name])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a `COALESCE` function:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?x (COALESCE(?dbpfn, ?dbpn, ?label) as ?name) 
WHERE { 
      ?x a foaf:Person .
      OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:fullname ?dbpfn }
      OPTIONAL { ?x dbpprop:name ?dbpn }
      OPTIONAL { ?x rdfs:label ?label }
}
LIMIT 100
```

[Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpprop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fx%20%28COALESCE%28%3Fdbpfn%2C%20%3Fdbpn%2C%20%3Flabel%29%20as%20%3Fname%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fx%20a%20foaf%3APerson%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx%20dbpprop%3Afullname%20%3Fdbpfn%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx%20dbpprop%3Aname%20%3Fdbpn%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fx%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%20100%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

`COALESCE` takes a list of arguments as input, and outputs the first of those arguments that does not correspond to an error. Since an unbound variable corresponds to an error, this will return the full name if it exists, otherwise the name if it exists, otherwise the label if it exists.

Comment: This doesn't work on either. It gives multiple answers for the same query. Take the 10 limit off and see how they pile up.

Comment: @Artemis well spotted, thanks, I overlooked the duplicates caused by multiple optional matches. The fix is simple, fortunately: add a DISTINCT keyword. Edited, see above.

Comment: If so, the queries I suggested also with a distinct will come up with the same result. I thought the point was to do it without distinct.

Comment: Bit unfortunate that you removed your answer, but from what I remember: no,  adding distinct would not have fixed your queries as they did not take property precedence into account. And who said anything about not using distinct?